# Erase only part of an image (currently entire image is erased)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a finger tap or drag to erase part of a UIImageView.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let panErase = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "erase:")
let tapErase = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "erase:")
imageBeingEdited.addGestureRecognizer(panErase)
imageBeingEdited.addGestureRecognizer(tapErase)
```

I'm not quite sure how to debug graphics context modifications, but this erases the whole image:

```
    let erasurePoint: CGPoint = gesture.locationInView(imageBeingEdited)
    println("\(erasurePoint.x) \(erasurePoint.y)")

    let image:UIImage = imageBeingEdited.image!
    let s = image.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(s)
    let g = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(g);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(g, CGRectMake(erasurePoint.x, erasurePoint.y, 5, 5))
    CGContextEOClip(g)
    image.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
    imageBeingEdited.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

The goal is to erase a circle at the tap location. What did I miss here? It looks like the image is cropped into a 5x5 circle, not necessarily at the tapped point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the code you've posted would result in clipping your image to a 5x5 ellipse, exactly as you describe.

Did you write this code, or copy it from somewhere else?

It needs to be rearranged so it first draws the image into the context, then draws your ellipse using a clear color and the drawing mode where the alpha of the source pixels is written to the destination. Don't muck around with the context's clipping path at all.

This doesn't look like very efficient code to me. On every change in the pan gesture you're creating a context, drawing an image into it, and then copying out a new image. Then, presumably, you're drawing the resulting image. That's not likely to be fast enough to keep up with the user's pan gesture.

Instead I would probably add a CAShapeLayer as a mask layer to my image view's layer and modify that mask layer's path, appending an ellipse to the mask path for each point the user touches. Even that might not be fast enough for smooth drawing. You might need to write code that interpolates between a beginning and end touch position and filling the whole segment.

Comment: I think you saved me a second question later. I'm updating the image in real time, yeah.

Comment: This is almost fast enough to work in realtime without a layer. I did testing, and on a 5s, you only rarely see two positions buffered waiting to erase.

At any rate, I run this off the main thread, buffer point locations, and replace the image on the main thread. This is incredibly smooth and works well. UIPanGestureRecognizer doesn't register enough points to do this well, so you need to interpolate depending on registered touch distance.

Comment: The key is do all of this off of the main thread, or the UI will not be responsive.